# Two bootstrap php-js forms on one page

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

A have two forms on one page created by [this tutorial on github](https://github.com/myprogrammingblog/myprogrammingblog.com/tree/master/UI%20Components/contact%20form). One is part of website page, another is in modal window

How to make it work independently, now id I press on submit button in on window it works in both

HTML

```html
<div class="container"> 
 <!-- Contacts -->
    <div class="contacts" id="contacts">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <h1>order a call</h1>
            <form id="contactForm">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name" required data-validation-required-message="name" />
                <p class="help-block"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="email" required data-validation-required-message=" email" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" placeholder="tel" required data-validation-required-message="tel" />
              </div>
              <div id="success"> </div> <!-- For success/fail messages -->
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-yellow btn-block">button1</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
 <br />

<div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-yellow btn-block" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >button2 (modal)</button>
</div>

     <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h2 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">order</h2>
            <p class="text-center">please leave your contact details</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body text-center">
            <form >
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="true" id="InputName" placeholder="InputName">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" required="true" id="InputTel" placeholder="InputTel">
              </div>
              <div id="success"> </div> <!-- For success/fail messages -->
              <button type="submit_modal" class="btn btn-yellow" id="submit_modal">go</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

PHP

```html
<?php
// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])    ||
   empty($_POST['email'])   ||
   empty($_POST['tel']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
 echo "No arguments Provided!";
 return false;
   }
 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
 
// create email body and send it 
$to = 'info@myemail.com'; // put your email
$email_subject = "Contact form submitted by:  $name";
$email_body = "request from website. \n\n".
      "name: $name \n ".
      "Email: $email_address\n tel: $tel";
$headers = "From: info@myemail.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;   
?>
```

JS

```js
/*
  Jquery Validation using jqBootstrapValidation
   example is taken from jqBootstrapValidation docs 
  */
$(function() {

 $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation(
    {
     preventSubmit: true,
     submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
      // something to have when submit produces an error ?
      // Not decided if I need it yet
     },
      submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();  
        var email = $("input#email").val(); 
        var tel = $("input#tel").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
         firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }        
       $.ajax({
              url: "/zvonoq/test4/bin/contact_me.php",
             type: "POST",
             data: {name: name, email: email, tel: tel},
             cache: false,
             success: function() {  
             // Success message
               $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
               $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
              .append( "</button>");
               $('#success > .alert-success').append("<strong>Ваш запрос отправлен. </strong>");
               $('#success > .alert-success').append('</div>');
           
               //clear all fields
               $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
              },
              
              error: function() {  
             // Fail message
               $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append( "</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry "+firstName+" it seems that my mail server is not responding...</strong> Could you please email me directly to <a href='mailto:me@example.com?Subject=Message_Me from myprogrammingblog.com'>me@example.com</a> ? Sorry for the inconvenience!");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
               //clear all fields
               $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                  },
        })
      },
      filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
      },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).tab("show");
    });
});
 

/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */ 
$('#name').focus(function() {
     $('#success').html('');
  });
```

also connected

Comment: elaborate your problem and show some code..

Comment: @NishantSolanki updated, sorry

Comment: so you are saying that both forms are getting submitted when you click any of the submit button??

Answer (score 0):

if you want to submit each form individually than you can try this..

first give different `id` to each form...

`<form id='id1'> .. </form>`..

and use `button instead of submit`. and call a javascript function on button click event to submit form..
`<input type='button' onclick='return submitForm('id1')'></button>`

and create a javascript function on bottom of your page

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function submitForm(id)
{
     document.getElementById(id).submit();
}
</script>
```

so you will have `two forms with two different ids and two buttons`...
let me know if any further help needed.